# Python Loading JSON config file on __init__

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to create a class that handles loading my config values.
So far this is what I have :

```
import os, json

class ConfigHandler:
    CONFIG_FILE = "/config.json"

    def __init__(self):
        print("init config")
        if os.path.exists(self.CONFIG_FILE):
            print("Loading config file")
            self.__dict__ = json.load(open(self.CONFIG_FILE))
        else:
            print("Config file not loaded")
```

Then in my main application class, I am doing :

```
from ConfigHandler import ConfigHandler
class MainApp:
     config =  ???
```

I have tried several ways to get the ConfigHandler to initialize, but it never hits the print statements. And I am not sure how to call the confighandler to get the dictionary.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you try `config = ConfigHandler().__dict__`?

Comment: having said that, the path `"/config.json"` being absolute seems unlikely to be found. Are you looking to open such a file relative to main.py or ConfigHandler.py?

Comment: You should separate "configuring your object with a `dict`" and "obtaining a `dict` from a JSON file". This makes it easier to create an instance of your object for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `config.json` in the root of your drive if using `CONFIG_FILE = "/config.json"`:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": "Mark"
}
```

Then:

```py
from ConfigHandler import ConfigHandler

config = ConfigHandler()  # Create an instance...calls __init__ implictly
print(config.a, config.b, config.c)
```

Will output:

```
1 2 Mark
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I needed. I was also missing a '.' at the location of the config file. It lives in the same location as the python colde, so should have been : CONFIG_FILE = "./config.json"

Answer (score 1):

Configure your object with a `dict`, and provide a separate class method for obtaining that `dict` from a JSON file.

```
class ConfigHandler:    
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, fh):
        return cls(json.load(fh))
```

Note, too, that the caller should be responsible for opening the file, not your `ConfigHandler` class.

```
with open("config.json") as f:
    c = ConfigHandler.from_json(f)
```

Comment: I don’t quite understand why the ConfigHandler wouldn’t load the json itself? Since I’m going to be using the ConfigHandler in several places, I would need to load the file and pass it in each place? That doesn’t make sense to me. I’m very new to python, so I’m obviously missing something.

Comment: Because the job of `ConfigHandler` is to manage a set of configuration options, not worry about who is *providing* the values for those options. By making it read from a file, you are forcing the user to *always* use a file, even if you already have some fixed set of options in mind. The most fundamental way to provide the options is to pass them directly; reading them from a file (or really, a file-like *object*) is just one other way to provide a set of values.

Comment: Even taking  a dict as an argument is probably too general. There are many, many, many different `dict` values that could be passed, and only a few of them actually use the *keys* that `ConfigHandler` would actually be interested in. Something like `def __init__(self, a: int, b: str, c: bool): ...` would be even better, with possibly a `from_dict` class method that handles the work of looking for the expected keys in an arbitrary `dict` in order to pass the associated values to `__init__` directly.

Comment: Put more simply, using the `__init__` definition in my previous comment as an example: is an instance of `ConfigHandler` *supposed* to allow arbitrary instance variables, or are you *assuming* that `d` will have exactly `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"` as keys in order to produce instance attributes named `a`, `b`, and `c`?